# Grouping does not create in master details rdlc report formatting

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc, rdl

I want to create a rdlc report using Microsoft Report Designer. Due to complexity of my data (the given below is just an example) I do not use View on Database side. So, I have to use seperate tables (data sources) for my report design. Now, as it can be seen the example below I have one report page and I want to show PERSONAL, FAMILY and JOB INFO for each person.

- There are Textboxes on PERSONAL INFO section. The data is come from table_Personal,
- There are a Table on FAMILY INFO section. The data is come from Table_Famiy,
- There are a Table on JOB INFO section. The data is come from Table_Job 
  and all the three tables contain Person_Id column.

PERSONAL INFO
Name : Christof
Surname : Robin
Age : 45

FAMILY INFO
No----- Name----- Age----- Birt Place
1------ Sarah----- 12------ London
2------ Albert----- 16------ Manchester
3------ David----- 23------ NY

JOB INFO
No------ Company----- Start Year
1------- Xyz----------- 2005
2------- T Mobile------- 1999
3------- Day Inn------- 1993

My question is;

1) I do not want to use Subreport and do not combine these tables in db side by using view (I have searchhed, but for 3 or more tables it is impossible I think). 
So, is it possible to create a master-detail report like above by grouping items (table, list, etc.) and without using subreport on rdlc? If so, could you explain a little bit please?

2) I have tried to create such a kind of report like that; I use a List and inserted all the textboxes and three tables above 
to this list. I assign all the three tables as Report Data Sources. I make List.DataSetName = Table_Personal and List.Grouping settings 
select Group on : Person_Id and some other combination. But, unfortunately I have not managed to create such a kind of report group like above.

Could you help me please by giving some advice and if you have some sample rdlc page source please? ...Shohel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible but I'd done it like 6 months ago, so I don't have any sample code right now.

I have done a lot of similar cases. One such case is there are a list of students and each student has a list of marks, a list of achievements, etc.

If I remember correctly I used one storedprocedure to get all the details of all the students. One dataset. And put 'em all in one tablix and grouped 'em.

The sub-lists (like the list of marks) are separate tablixes themselves and are inserted in textboxes of the main tablix.

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: Thank you Zarles Krieger for your cooperation.I mean to say that i won't use store procedure.I have to design from table this is my work. my project manager won't accept store procedure.

Comment: Yw. So no storedprocedures, ok. Now how are you planning to build the dataset in your report? :O

Comment: If you don't want to use anything on the db side, maybe in the dataset of your report, you could write a query and join all the tables and achieve the idea I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: You are right? But I can not do this job. How will i do this job? Do you have any sample project? Thanks.

Comment: Need some time to post it here. Can you wait?

Comment: You can look at the screenshot at http://tinypic.com/r/2u8idlx/5 and download the sample project from http://www.sendspace.com/file/6t0pbs please let me know if that's what you are looking for. And the tables are a bit sloppy.