# SQL Reporting services-Master Detail report. Need to have header outside of detail report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, subreport, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-grouping

I need to make a change to one of the report as explained below.

The current report is

[image]

I have used tablix in the report with PONumber as the group. Each PO can have one or more items.

Now the change required is the PO number needs to be shown above the report which includes lot of PO related details such as PO number, PO date, Vendor details etc.

So the new report should like below with pagebreak for every PO.

```
PO Number  PO Date      Vendor Name        Agent Name
    ----------------------------------------------------------
  P01004   31-Jul-2013  Microsoft          Josh


Slot       Prod         Unit  Size  Brand Ship Date
    ----------------------------------------------------------
 1       HDWR-SWM-0100  LBS   5lb  KUGANO 1-Aug-2013
 2       HDWR-SRG-0101  KGS   2KG  CASIO  1-Sep-2013

<pagebreak>

PO Number  PO Date      Vendor Name        Agent Name
    ----------------------------------------------------------
  P01006   31-Aug-2013  Cisco              John


Slot       Prod         Unit  Size  Brand Ship Date
    ----------------------------------------------------------
 1       HDWR-SWM-0200  OZ   5oz    OLIVER 1-Sep-2013
<pagebreak>
```

So far in the tablix report, I can't move PO as outside group.

What are my options here?

Thanks.

Comment: Create a subreport with the PO detail and please in the po tablix.

Comment: I've answered a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20171929/grouping-does-not-create-in-master-details-rdlc-report-formatting

Comment: @ZarlesKrieger: Thanks Zarles. I have downloaded the sample project but I am not getting how the whole thing was created. Please let me know if you can mention any steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I completed the report by using tablix in rectangle container. Then the rowGrouping & column grouping was set based on the data filtering.