# Generate Admit Card using RDLC

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, rdlc

I have a RDLC report like this one.

[image]

Here I can print one admit card each time for each student. I can collect the required data based on a student's roll no, academic calender and current session and pass that to the rdlc report to print that.

Now the problem is if I want to print/generate the admit cards for all students instead of printing one admit card each time what should I can do now? I can get all student's data but I have no idea how to represent them in report to achieve this goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem once.

I used one storedprocedure to get all the details of all the students. One dataset. And put them all in one tablix and grouped them.

The sub-lists (like the list of marks) are separate tablixes themselves and are inserted in textboxes of the main tablix.

I've answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20171929/grouping-does-not-create-in-master-details-rdlc-report-formatting/20175611#20175611).
You can download the sample project I created from [sendspace](https://www.sendspace.com/file/qjw6xk) and here is a [screenshot](http://tinypic.com/r/2u8idlx/5) of my example.

Hope it helps!